# Take snapshot of WKWebView without launching the web page

Tags: ios, uiview, webkit, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm looking to capture a snapshot of a WKWebView but without the view getting loaded. Essentially, the app user would copy a link to the app, the link should open in the background, have its snapshot taken, and then the image gets copied to the app.

Is this possible at all in the first place with WebKit (or even SFSafariWebServices)? I can capture the snapshot but only after a specific page has been launched with the desired web site.